# How to clear temporary files from Upload Center

Tags: microsoft-office, upload

I'm using Office 2013 with the **Upload Center** uploading files to a SharePoint.

I have one file stuck in the Center with the state "Path not found":

[image]

That is because while the was upload I moved/deleted it --> inconsistent state.

However I can't click on Resolve > Discard Changes:
*"The action can't be completed because the file is open."*

I also can't Resolve > Open to Resolve:
"File does not exist"*

I can't Resolve > Save a copy:
*"File does not exist"*

How do I tell Upload Center to forget all current uploads?

Comment: You try right click on the item?  Have you tried to restart your computer?  This would close all open file handles.

Comment: ... Yes of course I tried right clicking - it is the same menu as Resolve. Also I have restarted. I'm asking about a **specific** location which I can clear (registry/App Settings) so that the Upload Center forgets about its uploads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a solution, but a workaround:

I created an empty file at exactly the same location it should have been. I synced after that and I could safely remove the file.

Comment: I did however create the empty file using notepad specifying identically “file name”.”file extension” Then saving it as “all files” instead of .txt. This is the only way I could actually remove it. For whatever reason if I tried to complete the same action using Excel it didn’t work (I think it had to do with the file not being completely empty). The reason it wouldn’t upload the file and was stuck in the queue is SharePoint didn’t like my file extension (.tdms)

Answer (score 3):

1. Using task-manager, exit all processes associated with the Upload Center
2. delete all contents in the temporary folder i.e. 
   `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Office\15.0\OfficeFileCache`

ref: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_365hp-office_storage/microsoft-office-upload-center-stuck/42064b0c-1bfb-46d8-9fc9-56a50c006817?rtAction=1376465074458